# Move Azure VM from one OMS work-space to another using CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-cli

Is there a command to move Azure VM from one OMS( Log Analytics) work-space to the another OMS work-space  ?

I read the documentation of `AzureRmResource` but not sure if this is the right option ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your scenario, you need remove agent on your VM and install OMS agent with new OMS configuration. Here is the script you could use. I test in my lab, it works for me.

```
#!/bin/sh

# resource group name, vm nmae, OMS Id and OMS key.
rg=<resource group name>
vmname=<>
omsid="<>"
omskey=""

##Remvoe OMS agent from VM
az vm extension delete -g $rg --vm-name $vmname -n OmsAgentForLinux

# re-install and configure the OMS agent with your new OMS.
az vm extension set \
  --resource-group $rg \
  --vm-name $vmname \
  --name OmsAgentForLinux \
  --publisher Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring \
  --version 1.0 --protected-settings '{"workspaceKey": "'"$omskey"'"}' \
  --settings '{"workspaceId": "'"$omsid"'"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the command 'az vm extension set'.

Sample bash script for this.

```
#!/bin/sh

vmname=<Replace with your vm name>
rgname=<Replace with your Resource Group name>
omsid=<Replace with your OMS Id>
omskey=<Replace with your OMS key>

az vm extension set \
  --resource-group $rgname \
  --vm-name $vmname \
  --name OmsAgentForLinux \
  --publisher Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring \
  --version 1.0 --protected-settings '{"workspaceKey": "'"$omskey"'"}' \
  --settings '{"workspaceId": "'"$omsid"'"}'
```